# Producing multiple qplots with data.table

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I'd like to produce one scatter plot per group from a data.table and return it from a function.

I can produce the different charts using plot (below) so I assume this isn't a data.table issue:

```
dt = data.table(A = c(1,2,3,4), B = c(1,1,2,2), C = c(4,5,6,7))
result = dt[, list(plot = list(plot(A, C))), by = B]
```

However if I try to do the same with qplot (in order to get plots I can return), I appear to end up with two copies of the second chart.

```
dt = data.table(A = c(1,2,3,4), B = c(1,1,2,2), C = c(4,5,6,7))
result = dt[, list(plot = list(qplot(A, C))), by = B]
result[1,][["plot"]]
result[2,][["plot"]]
```

Apologies if I'm missing something obvious / doing something stupid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure exactly what's going on, but here is a workaround:

```
result = dt[, list(plot = list(qplot(data=.SD, A, C))), by = B]
```

It seems like `data.table` reserves an environment to execute its evaluations in in some way, and `qplot` just stores a reference to this environment.  Since you don't specify a `data` argument, `qplot` will look in that environment for the data, which keeps getting changed for each `by` value by `data.table`, so after the `data.table` operation, only the last piece is left there.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat, I think in a sense yes, though not by the typical promise evaluation mechanism.  I'm pretty sure `ggplot` stores the actual `aes` expressions, and then evaluates them in a specific stored environment / data.frame upon printing.  The effect is the same though.

Answer (score 1):

@BrodieG's answer is better, but here's another way:

```
plots <- lapply(unique(dt$B),function(x)ggplot_build(qplot(data=dt[B==x,],A,C)))
plots[1]
plots[2]
```